# Copy a MyEclipse workspace for a new workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, myeclipse

I have a my eclipse workspace as `UniversityApp`. I decided to copy from my workspace and rename it to `UniversityApp.2`. I copied original workspace with `UniversityApp.2` name but project in new workspace still linked to `UniversityApp` folder(by seeing at `Properties\Resource`).

What is it solution?

Comment: Copy your project folder and paste in new workspace and import in eclipse.

Comment: @IrenPatel I know this solution but is there any solution without import?

Answer (score 0):

my assumption is that your statement:

> but project in new workspace still linked to UniversityApp folder

is not correct.

When looking at Properties/Resource the value for Path in should be UniversityApp in both workspaces. However the Location will be different, one will be ../UniversityApp/UniversityApp and the other will be ../UniversityApp.2/UniversityApp. So there is no link between your two UniversityApp projects.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how projects in your UniversityApp workspace got location pointers to the workspace itself as this is normally the default and doesn't need specifying. In this case, you will really have to import the projects into a new workspace. Multiple projects can be imported at the same time, so it's not much different from copying the whole workspace. Create an empty workspace folder and open MyEclipse for that folder. Go to File->Import->General->Existing Projects into Workspace. Click "Select root directory" and browse to the folder for the other workspace. Now click "Select All", ensure that the "Copy projects into workspace" is selected and click Finish.

The location of the projects is held in a file deep within the .metadata folder but there is a separate file for each project and the file isn't really editable, so importing is the easiest method and not much slower than a copy.

If you want to retain your settings from the old workspace, open MyEclipse for the old workspace then go to File->Export->General->Preferences. Select the preferences to export and specify a file to export them to. Click Finish. Then open MyEclipse for the new workspace and Import the preferences in a similar way.